# Erro Typescript - Property 'colors' is missing in type '{ title: string; }' but required in type 'ButtonGradientProps'

Tags: typescript, react-native

Sou novo com o Typescript, estou tentando fazer um componente de um botão. O que estou fazendo de errado?

**Erro:**

> Property 'colors' is missing in type '{ title: string; }' but required in type 'ButtonGradientProps'.ts(2741)
> LinearGradient.d.ts(24, 5): 'colors' is declared here.

---

**Componente**

```
import { LinearGradientProps } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

import { Gradient, Button, Title } from './styles';

interface ButtonGradientProps extends LinearGradientProps {
  title: string;
}

export default function ButtonGradient({
  title,
  ...rest
}: ButtonGradientProps) {
  return (
    <Button>
      <Gradient
        colors={['#A2C11C', '#2C5D63']}
        start={{ y: 0.0, x: 0.0 }}
        end={{ y: 0.0, x: 1.0 }}
        {...rest}
      >
        <Title>{title}</Title>
      </Gradient>
    </Button>
  );
}
```

**CSS Componente**

```
import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export const Button = styled(TouchableOpacity)`
  width: 100%;
  height: ${RFValue(55)}px;
`;

export const Gradient = styled(LinearGradient)`
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

export const Title = styled.Text`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.fonts.medium_500};
  font-size: ${RFValue(15)}px;
`;
```

**Tela Welcome**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

import ButtonGradient from '../../components/ButtonGradient';
import theme from '../../global/styles/theme';
import {
  Container,
  ContainerNextPage,
  DivText,
  Text,
  LinkCadastro,
} from './styles';

export default function Welcome() {
  return (
    <Container>

      (...)

      <ContainerNextPage>
        <ButtonGradient title="Vamos lá!" />                      // Erro

        <DivText>
          <Text>Ainda não possui conta?</Text>
          <LinkCadastro>Cadastre-se agora!</LinkCadastro>
        </DivText>
      </ContainerNextPage>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O TS basicamente está dizendo que `colors` é uma prop obrigatória, que faltou passar quando você invocou o componente:

```
<ButtonGradient title="Vamos lá!" />  // falta o "colors"
```

Quando você definiu seu componente `ButtonGradient`, você especificou suas props como:

```
interface ButtonGradientProps extends LinearGradientProps {
  title: string;
}
```

Embora você não tenha especificado que seu componente exige uma prop `color`, você disse que ele recebe todas as props do `LinearGradientProps`. Se você navegar pra `LinearGradientProps` vai existir uma prop obrigatória `color` lá.

Uma solução simples seria remover o `extends LinearGradientProps`. O TS vai parar de reclamar deste erro. Só que se você quiser passar qualquer outra prop ao `<ButtonGradient />`, ele vai reclamar. Quando ele reclamar, você pode ir adicionando as props necessárias uma a uma.

Outra solução simples seria declarar que o objeto aceita qualquer propriedade, assim:

```
interface ButtonGradientProps {
  title: string;
  [key: string]: any
}
```

Neste caso o TS vai deixar passar qualquer prop, sendo permissivo até demais. Se você passar uma prop que não existe nem no `LinearGradient`, ele não vai reclamar.

E agora vou passar a alternativa mais complexa: Definir as props de entrada como uma união entre `{ title }` + `LinearGradientProps` porém tornando opcional o `colors`...

```
type ButtonGradientProps = 
  { title: string } & 
  Omit<LinearGradientProps, 'color'> &
  Optional<Pick<LinearGradientProps, 'color'>>
```

Note que todas as alterações mencionadas acima não fazem alteração nenhuma no JS gerado. Estamos apenas dando "dicas" diferentes pro TS checar o seu código.

Eu pessoalmente recomendaria que você ficasse com a opção 1 ou 2, às vezes vale a pena sacrificar a "precisão da checagem de tipos" por mais produtividade. O caso 3 é para se você estiver escrevendo uma biblioteca, ou caso esteja com tempo.

Comment: Ótima explicação, resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado!!